# How to load dynamic images define in angularjs framework through webpack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Currently, when I execute `yarn dev`, I have images in my bundle and also in `images` folder in dist directory. I have also same image in my bundle and in `images` in dist, it depends on how images are loaded (`<img src="*">`, `<img ng-src="*">`).

First, I copied images with `copy-webpack-plugin` but some images were in my bundle and/or in `images` (due to copy) in dist.
I have tried with `file-loader` and `url-loader` to load this images but I have always cases that images are not correctly loaded.

Please, be careful of my files tree.

app/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div style="float: left">
        <label style="display: block">Sun in src</label>
        <img src="../images/sun.svg" width="200px">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 100px">
        <label style="display: block">Sun in ng-src</label>
        <img ng-src="{{imgSun}}" width="200px">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 100px">
        <label style="display: block">Cloud in ng-src</label>
        <img ng-src="{{imgCloud}}" width="200px">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app/app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.imgSun = 'images/sun.svg';
    $scope.imgCloud = 'images/cloud.svg';
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const distDirectory = 'webpack-dist';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    bail: true,
    entry: {'myApp': ['./app/index.html', './app/app.js']},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.svg$/, use: 'file-loader'},
            /*{
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [{loader: 'file-loader', options: {name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'}}],
                include: path.resolve('images'),
            },*/
            //{test: /\.svg$/, use: 'url-loader', include: path.resolve('images')},
            {test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader'},
        ]
    },
    watch: true,
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: path.resolve('app/index.html')}),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({host: 'localhost', server: {baseDir: [path.resolve(distDirectory)]}})
    ],
    output: {filename: '[name].bundle.js', path: path.resolve(distDirectory)}
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --open"
  }
}
```

I would like to have all images in my bundle.
I do not want duplicated data (bundle and `images`folder) in my dist.
Therefore, I will be able to add `[hash]` to my bundle and have no more problem with browser cache.